# Change output property name in linq select statement

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc

I wish to rename the following properties in the select statement so that the output properties are camel case (`Id = id and LockedEntityId = lockedEntityId`)

```
var locks = _service.GetContext().Locks
            .Where(x => x.DossierId == dossierId)
            .Select(x => new {x.Id, x.LockedEntityId })
            .ToList();

string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(locks);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing it is very easy: just specify them.

```
var locks = _service.GetContext().Locks
            .Where(x => x.DossierId == dossierId)
            .Select(x => new {id = x.Id, lockedEntityId = x.LockedEntityId })
            .ToList();
```

I would, if possible, advise to use JSON.NET's (or a similar framework) annotations to specify the correct JSON data though. It will make your code more descriptive as it clearly conveys the intent of why you are doing this.

Answer (score 1):

```
var locks = _service.GetContext().Locks
        .Where(x => x.DossierId == dossierId)
        .Select(x => new {id = x.Id, lockedEntityId = x.LockedEntityId })
        .ToList();
```